# Print output of loop in same line python?

Tags: python

I am new to learning python and a bit confused and hoping i can get some help.

I have a dict here

```
my_dict = { "abc":1, "bvc":2, "mnb":3}
```

I am getting the keys using :-

```
keys = my_dict.keys()
for key in keys:
print(key)
```

and i get the output:-

```
"abc"
"bvc"
"mnb"
```

How can i get the output in the same line like this?

```
"abc", "bvc", "mnb"
```

I tried using

```
print(key.join(' ')+',')
```

in my loop but it doesn't work as expected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `list(my_dict.keys())` ?

Comment: Use print(key,end=", ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid printing a new line every time you can use `print(key, end="")` or also `print(key, end=", ")` and can then make so that it does not write the last comma.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```py
print(*my_dict.keys())
```

will unpack the keys into an argument list for `print` and product output

```
abc bvc mnb
```

If you need commas in the output, you can add the `sep=", "` keyword:

```py
print(*my_dict.keys(),sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a make a `string.join`

```
print(', '.join(my_dict.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default print() method add the new line character , if we want to override this then we need pass the explicitly char..

```
print(key,end=", ")
```